# Waning Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via UIManager['getConstants']

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I'm facing this warning in my react native expo app. I also attached my `package.json` file code. Please let me know the solution for it. Thanks

> Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via
>   UIManager['getConstants'] is no longer supported. Use
>   UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('getConstants') instead.
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:67:8 in warn
>   - node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:17:23 in warn
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\UIManager.js:164:12 in get
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\defineLazyObjectProperty.js:42:18
>   in getValue
>   - node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\createHandler.js:39:2 in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\NativeViewGestureHandler.js:3:0
>   in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\createNativeWrapper.js:3:0 in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\GestureHandler.js:1:0 in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\Swipeable.js:10:0 in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\index.js:1:0 in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\views\StackView\StackViewLayout.js:1:942
>   in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\views\StackView\StackView.js:1:670
>   in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\navigators\createStackNavigator.js:1:122
>   in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\index.js:1:35 in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   * App.js:3:0 in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:4:0 in 
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:197:45 in guardedLoadModule
>   * null:null in global code

Package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 1.3.0 version of react-native-gesture-handler.

```
    "dependencies": {
          "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    },
```

Type the code given below in terminal to install:

```
    npm install react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Please recheck my package.json code. "react-native-gesture-handler" version is already 1.3.0

Comment: Oh!! Sorry, I didn't notice at all. But that worked for me!! Try with yarn once, if you haven't.

Comment: if nothing works, try this  in your terminal once.  **expo r -c**

Comment: Can confirm this fixed my issue when I used with `yarn add react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0` as well.